# How to control hyperlink fields in gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I have a gridview in my asp.net page. Here it is:

[image]

[image]

Here is what i want to do: I have a database that keeps the information about which student is registered to which course. So by using that database, when a hyperlink is clicked, i first want to take coursename, coursecode, and term of the specific row that was clicked, and then make the query and show the seach results in another gridview. But i do not know how to take the values of specific rows and columns, for example how to take the value of Row(1)Col(1), when clicked the first view student list link. Here is the gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="instCourses" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="instCourses_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Registered Students" 
            NavigateUrl="InstViewCourses.aspx" Text="View Student List" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. You can use row command event of grid view and based link click you can handle event.

Here is the example for that.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21163/Trick-Tip-Raise-a-GridView-RowCommand-event-from-a

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jun/07/GridView-and-CommandArguments

Another way you directly bind event with click attribute.

Comment: just one more quick question, you see that my column in which i have link buttons is at the leftmost column, but i want it to be at the rightmost column but cannot find how to do it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you may complete this work by using `RowCommand` event of Grid View. When you will click on `Button` placed inside `Grid View` then this event will fire.

**Grid View** -

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdtest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        onrowcommand="grdtest_RowCommand" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="OrderID" SortExpression="OrderID" DataField="order_id" />
        <asp:ButtonField Text="View Student List" CommandName="View Student List" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

**Code -**

```
protected void grdtest_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.CommandName == "View Student List")
            {
                int Index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = grdtest.Rows[Index];
                int id= Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
                //if you want to select the text of different cells like `coursename` and `coursecode` then assign their cell number,it always start from 0.
               // Now you have the data of selected row.
               // Do what ever you want.
            }
    }
```

Note -

> Not forget to assign `CommandName` to `button`.

Hope you understand and works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Code

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Your Coulmn", "vacating.aspx?cont_id={0}") %>'  ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">Vacating req</asp:HyperLink>
```